# Bash grep output filename and line no without matches

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, cut

I need to get a list of matches with grep including filename and line number but without the match string

I know that `grep -Hl` will give only file names and `grep -Hno` will give filename with only matching string. But those not ideal for me. I need to get a list without match but with line no. For this `grep -Hln` doesn't work. I tried with `grep -Hn 'pattern' | cut -d " " -f 1` But it doesn't cut the filename and line no properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pointing it well with `cut`, only that you need the `:` field separator. Also, I think you need the first and second group. Hence, use:

```
grep -Hn 'pattern' files* | cut -d: -f1,2
```

#### Sample

```
$ grep -Hn a a*
a:3:are
a:10:bar
a:11:that
a23:1:hiya

$ grep -Hn a a* | cut -d: -f1,2
a:3
a:10
a:11
a23:1
```

Answer (score 3):

awk can do that in single command:

```
awk '/pattern/ {print FILENAME ":" NR}' *.txt
```

Comment: seems this is a good option too. Not much familiar with awk I think it's time to learn. Tnx

Comment: Yes it is better because it does everything in single command ( no need of multiple piped commands )

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this, just line numbers:

```
grep -nh PATTERN /path/to/file | cut -d: -f1
```

example output:

```
12
23
234
...
```

Unfortunately you'll need to use `cut` here. There is no way to do it with pure `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grep -RHn Studio 'pattern' | awk -F: '{print $1 , ":",  $2}'
```